# Форматированный вывод в строку

Tags: c++, c

```
itoa(rand()%10000, pin, 10);
```

Генерит 4х значное число. НО иногда оно генерит числа 0..999.

```
Получается
1507
6587
25 !! а нужно чтобы записало как 0025
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%04d", value)`?

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать функцию `sprintf` вместо `itoa`.
Например

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[5];


    for ( int x = 1; x < 10000; x = 10 * x + x % 10 + 1 )
    {        
        sprintf( s, "%04d", x );

        puts( s );
    }        
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0001
0012
0123
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include < iostream >    
 #include < iomanip >     // манипуляторы ввода/вывода
int main () 
{
    char * pin;
    itoa(rand()%10000, pin, 10);
    std::cout << std::setfill ('0') << std::setw (4);// setw количество выводимых элементов
                                                    //fill устанавливает заполнители
    std::cout << pin<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```